# git best practice and avoid cherry picking

Tags: git, branch

I'm rather new to git but start to love it, although I believe I'm not using it correctly. I've got 3 branches in one of our projects - dev, staging and pro, corresponding to 3 different servers, for development, staging and production. We're usually adding new branches for any support and feature tickets our client files to us, and usually work on different branches at the same time.

When a new functionality is ready to be testet on dev, we would merge the branch into dev and test it, and maybe do the last fixes directly in the dev branch (I guess here we should be going back into the feature's branch and do it there and re-merge?).

The problem we have is that to go from dev to staging with one of the features, we usually have to cherry pick as on dev + staging we might have a mixture of different features beeing tested, and thus quite often run into issues with some missing commits etc.

What are we doing wrong or how would you suggest to improve our process?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Git-Flow model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)? Your approach seems close enough to it (`dev` -> `develop`, `staging` -> release branch, `pro` -> `master`), but Git-Flow only involves merges, no cherry-picks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like you do cherry-pick just because you want to choose the features/fixes you want.

If you create one branch for each feature and each fix, you will be no longer cherry-picking because your are just merging branches.

Comment: that's why we started to create the branches, the issue is more that we're not sure where to base the feature branches, as on the dev branch we might have different features being under development and about to be integrated, and if we merge today a new feature to dev that, as decided later, should go online before anotherone already in the dev environment, we're merging new functionalities that should not be online yet, I hope I'm able to make clear what I mean ...